# How to decrypt or convert Python Dictionary of lists to normal dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Very new to python and literally struggling to get this fixed. I have dictionary like below from json file. I believe this is being called as Dictionary of lists.

```
MyDict = [{Key:[1,2,3,4]}, {Summary:[Text 1, Text 2, Text 3, Text 4]}]
```

Expected Result:
How to convert this to

```
{Key:1, Summary:Text 1}
{Key:2, Summary:Text 2}
{Key:3, Summary:Text 3}
{Key:4, Summary:Text 4}
```

No idea on how to achieve this..

Comment: zip the values of the first item in the list

Comment: I think you have the names of dictionaries and lists mixed up. You say this is a dictionary of lists, and you call the main list `MyDict`. A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) contains key-value pairs, and are represented with `{}` brackets. [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) are just a list of values, represented by `[]` brackets. So what you have here, is a list of dicts of lists.

Comment: yes correct and apologize pls. How to unpack this  list of dicts of lists to normal dict ?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the new information provided in other comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can iterate through the list:

```
   MyDict = {'Key':[1,2,3,4], 'Summary':['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4']}

result = []
for i in range(len(MyDict['Key'])):
    key = MyDict['Key'][i]
    summary = MyDict['Summary'][i]
    result.append({ 'Key': key, 'Summary': summary })

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'Key': 1, 'Summary': 'Text 1'}, {'Key': 2, 'Summary': 'Text 2'}, {'Key': 3, 'Summary': 'Text 3'}, {'Key': 4, 'Summary': 'Text 4'}]
```

Comment: Terribly sorry my data is not with [ ]. Instead it is with { }. Key is a list and Value is also a list. Kindly help..

MyDict = { {'Key':[1,2,3,4]}, {'Summary':['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4']} }

Comment: Not an issue. I have edit the code

Comment: Amazing.. But it is still inside [ ]. So it is saying as list. I want to get this as a dictionary for importing in to sql server

Answer (score 0):

I would start by extracting the lists from the data, as it would be easier to work with.

```py
keys = MyDict[0]['Key']
values = MyDict[1]['Summary']
```

Then you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the two lists together and loop over them like so

```py
res = []
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    res.append({'Key': k, 'Summary': v})
```

---

Given the new data, it looks like is should actually be.

```py
MyDict = {'Key':[1,2,3,4], 'Summary':['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4']}
```

So the only change you would need to make is to remove the indices when extracting the list.

```py
keys = MyDict['Key']
values = MyDict['Summary']
```

###### Output

```py
[
    {'Key': 1, 'Summary': 'Text 1'},
    {'Key': 2, 'Summary': 'Text 2'},
    {'Key': 3, 'Summary': 'Text 3'},
    {'Key': 4, 'Summary': 'Text 4'}
]
```

---

If you want to save it as a dictionary, not a list you can do:

```py
res = {}
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    res[k] = v
```

The output of this would be a dictionary where each key is a number and the value is the summary:

```py
{
    1: 'Text 1',
    2: 'Text 2',
    3: 'Text 3',
    4: 'Text 4'
}
```

---

If you want to do something with them as individual dictionaries you can do an operation on them instead of storing them in another dictionary.

```py
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    do_something({k: v})
```

This would call `do_something` with a new dict for each key-value pair, so the first would be `{1: 'Text 1'}` and so on.

Comment: Terribly sorry my data is not with [ ]. Instead it is with { }. Key is a list and Value is also a list. Kindly help..

MyDict = { {'Key':[1,2,3,4]}, {'Summary':['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4']} }

Comment: @JamesDataAnalyst Is that the raw json or the actual python object? You cannot have a dict like that in python. Also please update your question with these details.

Comment: it is Python response saved as .json file

Comment: I still believe that something is wrong with your data, since what you have provided is not valid JSON

Comment: I double checked now. data is like MyDict = { 'Key':[1,2,3,4], 'Summary':['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4'] }

i think it is just dictionary of lists

Comment: Great. My answer has been updated

Comment: Amazing.. But it is still inside [ ]. So it is saying as list. I want to get this as a dictionary for importing in to sql server